# How to get setTimeout to start counting as soon as the alert box is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert, settimeout

I currently have a function that creates alerts using the alert() function inside of the `setTimeout()` function, and that is nested inside of a for loop.

So it looks something like this

```
for(i<10){
 setTimeout(function(param){
  alert(param);
 3000, param);
  i++
}
```

The issue i am having when i do this is, the timer only starts counting after i click ok on the alert box.

So the first alert pops up, i click ok, 3 seconds later the second box appears.

Instead, I want to be able to have the first alert appear, wait 3 seconds, press ok, and the second alert to appear immediately

How can i do this?

Edit: I tried setInterval isntead of setTimeout as suggested but it seems to cause me to get stuck in a set interval loop?

Here is my code:

```
for (var product in cart) {
    alert(product);
    setTimeout(function(item) {
        alert("Name: " + item + ": Quantity: " + cart[item]);
    }, i * 3000, product);
    i++;
}
```

I just tried replacing setTimeout with setInterval, I also tried clearInterval right after and the box is not even appearing

Comment: You should use `setInterval` instead of what you did. Also, your for loop is invalid. It should be a while loop if anything...

Comment: where is item being defined?

Comment: Also why is there three arguments in setTimeout?

Comment: the 3rd parameter of setTimeout should be the argument of the function i believe, so item = product

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)** for executing code with certain interval of time. Use **[`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval)** for canceling the **[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)** action.

```js
var i = 0,
  param = 'hi';
var intr = setInterval(function(param) {
  if (++i === 10)
    clearInterval(intr);
  console.log(param);
}, 3000, param);
```

In your case you can get object keys into an array using **[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)**, then inside **[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)** you can get it using index.

```js
var i = 0,
  cart = {
    car: 1,
    car1: 2,
    car2: 3,
    car3: 4,
    car4: 5,
    car5: 6,
    car6: 7,
    car7: 8,
    car8: 9,
    car9: 10
  },
  // getting object keys
  arr = Object.keys(cart);
// initializing interval
var intr = setInterval(function(p) {
  // getting value using key
  alert('Name : ' + p[i] + ' Quantity : ' + cart[p[i]]);
  // canceling interval
  if (++i === 10)
    clearInterval(intr);
}, 3000, arr);
```

Comment: I found a better way to do this with Object.keys

Comment: upvoted, now that you used keying. It prevents for loops that need to be blocked from continuation.

Answer (score 1):

Updated to work while iterating through properties of the products:
I made it simple by keeping a setInterval and got the object properties with `Object.keys(obj)`

```
var products = {
    sexdoll: '$69',
    dog: '$0',
    soul: '$minimum wage'
}, keyedProducts = Object.keys(products);

var i=0, intval = setInterval(function() {
    alert(keyedProducts[i]);
    if(++i > keyedProducts.length-1) { clearInterval(intval) }
}, 3000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xybt1g9x/

Comment: unfortunately i have to use the for loop because i am using for(var product in cart)

Comment: @StevenHsu updated it to be as short as possible. It will spit out each property in your products every 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop will execute as fast as possible, so your timeouts are just going to be called at `t~=0 + timeout` which won't be noticeable.

What you need is to increment a variable and set your timeouts to that `variable*timeout`.

Also, the call to `window.alert` stops the execution of your scripts. You may need to use some other way to show your info-box (like a modal-window) :

```js
var obj = {x:1, y:2, z:3}
var i = 0;
var now = performance.now();
for(var p in obj){
  setTimeout(function(){snippet.log(this +' __ '+  (performance.now()-now));}.bind(obj[p]), ++i*3000);
  }
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is what i was doing initially, but when doing it this way the timer doesnt start until i close the first alert box, i would like the timer to start as soon as the first alert box appears

Comment: this is because `window.alert()` stops the execution of the javascript. Use something else than alert (i.e a modal window) to avoid it.